# How do I write unit tests for a single JS file?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have a single js file with a function in in. I want to write unit tests for the function and deliver the tests and file to someone. It needs to be standalone.

Here is my project:

```
src: myFunction.js
tests: empty for now
```

myFunction.js:

```
function HelloWord() {
   return 'Hello';
}
```

It would be great to have a test file like this:

```
import { func } from './myFunction.js';

describe('tests', function () {
    it('returns hello', function () {
        expect(func()).toEqual('Hello');
    });
});
```

I don't know which unit test framework would be the easiest and fastest to accomplish what I need to do. The user needs to get my directory and just run the tests from the command line.

Comment: check `mocha`. Is really fast to setup.

Answer (score 7):

Using Mocha, a really fast set up would be:

1) Install mocha to package.json:

```
npm install --save-dev mocha
```

2)Write down the test. Let it be `test.js` under `/tests/` , for example:

```
var myFunc = require('./myFunction');

var assert = require('assert');
describe('the function' , function(){
    it('works' , function(){
        assert.equal( myFunc() , 'hello');
    });
});
```

3) Set up the `package.json` test command:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "test": "node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/test.js"
    }
}
```

4) Call tests by `npm test`.

Comment: Import and export do not work. How can I get the function from the file without using ES6?

Comment: The set up I wrote was using `node.js`. As far as I know, at the moment you must to transpile the ES6 modules code to make it work in any browser or any nodejs version, using `babel` for example. In the other hand, If you need to test code that runs in a browser -it's not clear in the question-, you may need to use karma (https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html), which makes the set up a little more complex than just running a `mocha` script.

Comment: How do I know if I need to run the tests in a browser? There is another simple app with a index.html file but not all code is in the html file.

Comment: If your code needs to run in a browser, you should test it in a browser. Sure there are some modules that are pure logic and don't interact with the browser, but any code that reads/manipulates html, trigger browser apis etc. etc should be tested in browsers. If it is javascript for a web page -that seems to be the case since you say there's an `index.html`- you should use `karma` I believe (and that invalidates my answer).

Comment: Ok thanks so much for that. Can I use karma for the original question as well?

Comment: You need `karma` in order to use any test suite in a browser. Usually, `karma` is used with `jasmine`.Check any tutorials on the subject. Your question is to wide and open to provide a solution with a working example. If you try `karma` and fail making it to work, update your answer with your project folder structure, the script you want to test -at least the important bits-, your spec and your karma configuration and someone will help you for sure.

Comment: What would you need to do to the myFunction.js file to get the Mocha example to work? I get a failure for the require() call. ("Cannot find module ...")

Comment: Well, don't know about your specific setup, but if you're getting a 'Cannot file module error', chances are your path to the module in the `require()` call is wrong. I don't think it has to do with your module code or even the karma setup, but is difficult to tell with this info. Maybe you should open a new question.

Comment: I had to do a slight modification to get this to work: `"test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/test.js"`

Comment: Or simply run `npx mocha` to run the tests